# Add to Jekyll social share buttons

Tags: javascript, svg, jekyll, share-button

I am pretty new to Jekyll, but I am trying to build my own tech blog over it. I want to add to each post a footer containing a list of buttons (icons) to share to social networks an article. Searching around for a solution, I've seen that such buttons are implemented using *SVG images*.

So, inside the `post.html` file, I've added an include to a `share.html` file, where to refer to these *share buttons*.

The problem is: where have I to put the SVG icons? I've seen over the Internet that in many jekyll blogs' filesystem there are not SVG file at all, What the hell is going on?

**EDITED**
I know that it is possible to inline an svg icon using the `svg` tag. But it is not what I meant. I post here an example that I found

```
 <a href="https://twitter.com/share?url={{ site.url }}{{ page.url }}&amp;text={{ page.title | cgi_escape }}"
    title="Share on Twitter" class="button">
       <span class="count count-twitter">0</span>
          <i class="icon icon-twitter notranslate" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </a>
```

I've searched for `icon-twitter` class in all the Git repository, but I did not find that anywhere.

Comment: Maybe I'm getting you wrong, but are you just asking how to display `.svg` files in Jekyll?

Comment: I am asking which are the best practices to view SVG icons. I can't understand the one that I gave as example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found the answer to my question. On the internet there are some cool sites that give you the oppotunity to link their SVG icons, hosted on some CDN.

For example, take a look at [Font Awsome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/). As stated in the [Get Started](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) section, you can link their resources in your site:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

I've put the `link` instruction into the `head.html` file. Then you can add one of their awsome svg icon to your site using some CSS and the `<i>` element, like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i>
```

This instruction adds a [*stackoverflow*](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/stack-overflow/) logo icon that you can style as you want.

Answer (score 3):

In the base jekyll install, social icons are inline svg.
Have a look in the [_includes/footer.html](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/site_template/_includes/footer.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I updated my question adding some missing detail.

Comment: I post a dead link.

Answer (score 1):

> I am asking which are the best practices to view SVG icons

Do you have each icon as an actual `.svg` image file?

If yes, just treat them exactly like any other image file *(`.jpg`, `.png`, whatever)*.
Put them into a folder of your choice *(for example `/images`)* and use the `<img>` tag to show them:

```
<img src="/images/icon.svg" />
```

Or if you're using Markdown:

```
![alt text](/images/icon.svg)
```